# What is MASM ? which we generally use it for learning assembly language code?

Tags: assembly

In 8086 processor,what ic's we use are different...i think they are of 16 bit...but we practice the code in 64 bit computers..how is it possible?please expalin>>>>What is MaSm actually?? and can you explain me where I can get the software....

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. As for MASM - it's is an assembler from Microsoft. See [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler)

Comment: I would down-vote, but at 1 rep... I'll even give an up-vote for "noobness" ;-) Questions in SO usually work better if there is some *prior research shown* and if there is a specific question. For instance, see the Wikipedia [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) and [8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) as brief overviews. Once the basic "what's" are understood, much better (and perhaps interesting) questions can be asked.

Answer (score 4):

MASM is microsoft's macro assembler. The Microsoft Assembler has been in production since 1981 and is upgraded by Microsoft to keep abreast with operating system needs and processor developments. for compatibilities issues check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler)

can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1c9da0-0510-44a2-b042-7ef370530c64)

Answer (score 4):

MASM - is the Microsoft Macro Assembler. It is an assembler. It takes your code
pre-processes it and converts it to binary. The links it to runnable executable or an OBJect file.

all Intel processors 32bit and em64t processors (80386 and up) support the 8086 compatability mode called "real mode". Wich means that all PCs to this day are backward compatible with say MS-DOS and all the games that used to run on IBM XT. Those will run on modern machines but really fast so those will be unplayable :-)

All PCs to this day are booting with their processor in the real mode and modern operating systems switch the processor to the 32bit/64bit "protected mode".

Basically what happens in real mode is that the CPU knows it is working as 8086. 
E.g : all operations are on 16bit registers and the memory is addressed by a segment:offset
pair. The memory addresses are physical memory addresses and you have access to the first 1MB of RAM. 
Physical address is calculated by segment shifted left by 4 bits + offset. 
Thus 8000h:100h is the same address as 8010h:0h , physical address is 80100h in the memory.

Some modern machines have EFI instead of BIOS and those boot in the "protected mode" from the start. MAC machines are like that.

Answer (score 2):

Ans. MASM: Microsoft Macro Assembler
The Microsoft Macro Assembler (MASM) is an assembler for the x86 family of microprocessors, originally produced Microsoft MS-DOS operating system. It supported a wide variety of macro facilities and structured programming idioms, including high-level constructions for looping, procedure calls and alternation (therefore, MASM is an example of a high-level assembler). Later versions added the capability of producing programs for the Windows operating systems that were released to follow on from MS-DOS. MASM is one of the few Microsoft development tools for which there was no separate 16-bit and 32-bit version.
Assembler affords the programmer looking for additional performance a three pronged approach to performance based solutions. MASM can build very small high performance executable files that are well suited where size and speed matter. When additional performance is required for other languages, MASM can enhance the performance of these languages with small fast and powerful dynamic link libraries. For programmers who work in Microsoft Visual C/C++, MASM builds modules and libraries that are in the same format so the C/C++ programmer can build modules or libraries in MASM and directly link them into their own C/C++ programs.
This allows the C/C++ programmer to target critical areas of their code in a very efficient and convenient manner, graphics manipulation, games, very high speed data manipulation and processing, parsing at speeds that most programmers have never seen, encryption, compression and any other form of information processing that is processor intensive.

Answer (score 1):

MASM stands for "microsoft macro assembler". In modern (32 and 64 bit) here's the so called "real mode" which supports also 16, and even 8, bit register, for backward compatibility. Basically a processor "emulates" an older one so programs designed for that processor will run even on newer ones. For MASM just ask google.
 I suggest you using [Easy Code](http://www.easycode.cat/English/index.htm) with MASM. It's an IDE that allows you to build win32 executables using assembly language.

Comment: Do NOT visit the website since it's infected (URL:blacklist). AVG just saved my day